# MySQL syntax - adding a primary key. What does the following mean?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have the following syntax from an SQL tutorial. It updates a table to add a primary key constraint to a column.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)
```

What exactly is the pk_PersonID? Is this just an identifier? Must this unique right across the entire database?

Thanks indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an identifier for the constraint and must be unique. For example, if you want to delete the constraint later you can do

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
DROP CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID;
```

Comment: The name of the constraint must be unique within the schema that the table belongs to. Constraints can have the same name if they belong to a table in a different schema.